# Firebase Project deleted but still showing connected in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project in android studio 3.1.3 which i had connected with Firebase for cloud messaging.Due to some problem i deleted the project from firebase account and reversed the complete process in Android studio like deletion of google json file removing firebase related dependencies from gradle files.Now when i try to reconnect the project to Firebase using another account using assistant in Android Studio ,it shows Project is already connected and prompts for sync only.How i can connect  my project with the new account.

My app module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' .  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'  
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

ext {
support_version = '26.1.0'
} .  
android {   
compileSdkVersion 26  
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3' .  
defaultConfig {  
    applicationId “in.co.test”  
    minSdkVersion 23  
    targetSdkVersion 26  
    versionCode 4  
    versionName "2.4"   
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"  
    multiDexEnabled true
}  
buildTypes  
{  
    release {
        minifyEnabled true  
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'  
    }  
} 
packagingOptions {  
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' 
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'  
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'  
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'  
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
} 
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"  
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"  
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"  
implementation "com.android.support:design:$support_version"  
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"  
implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.7"  
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:4.3.1'  
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'   
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"  
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'  

}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Post `Gradle: Module` code. Also, did you try Clean/Rebuild?

Comment: i tried with clean/rebuild...but no success.

Comment: Is there anything in your Manifest That could possibly reference Firebase such as Metadata?

Comment: I have checked in gradle : project as well as manifest ttoo here is no reference of firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @grant for your reply.
Finally i solved by following below steps:-
1)removed google-services.json
2)removed dependencies :

from gradle -project

```
dependencies{
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
}
```

from gradle-module

```
dependencies{
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
}
```

removing any service class entry in menifest file ,created extending FirebaseInstanceIdService.